# The meaning of curly brace on import section on React | Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am a beginner at React/Redux. My question is why do some components/elements have {} and some (Thunk, React, Combine) do not {} around it. I am curious about the how they work; I would appreciate for a detailed description. Thank you.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import Thunk from "redux-thunk";
import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from "redux";
import combine from "./redux/combine";

const store = createStore(
  combine,
  applyMiddleware(
    Thunk
  )
)

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Text>Hi</Text>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: They are named vs. default exports...Read about exports here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Comment: Please check out any ES6 tutorial and the MDN docs for [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically ES6 modules can export default and parameterized references. Default is the one accessed via `import moduleName from 'module';` where you don't care about its name as you can use any identifier name instead of `moduleName`, while with parameterized export every exported value has its key like `import { connect } from 'react-redux';`